# Firefox Firebug Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed

Tags: console, firebug

Getting the following in the Firebug console:

```
! Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed.
```

How do I determine what is causing this error? Can't figure out what 'resource' it's talking about.

I don't see anything missing on the page(s) in question.

Comment: Do you have a URL, so this message can be reproduced by others?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

Use the following process:

- Go to the Network tab
- Enable the Network tab
- Reload the page
- Look for requests with `404` response codes

Comment: My Network tab did not show any 404 requests - in my case, I simply had an empty attribute in my HTML element (`<source src="" type="video/mp4"`). Maybe it will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this - the EXPECTED response if the src is null is to get an error, so the solution for that part is to define a src value.  However, even with a valid src, I sometimes get the same error - not always, it depends on something else which I haven't determined, however:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="http://localhost/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://localhost/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

works consistently for me, when if I only have the source attribute once it fails.

Comment: I believe your issue with "only some video files" showing this is codex issue. I have some vid files I produced and if I select them, i get this same error. But if I select a file downloaded form Youtube, it works fine. I'm thinking we might be able to play with type or some other parameter. It seems to hint "base64" in error message. You shouldn't have to declare it twice.